# ¿Qué quiere decir "apenas acabas, ven" en este caso y por lo general?

Tags: definiciones

Tengo la ventaja de oir los voces cuando no es claro quien habla.
uno chico, se llama Ricardo fue detenido. Su Madre dice a Daniel, un amiga de Ricardo:

> — Ricardo está en la comisaría — dice.
>
> —¿Qué ha pasado? —pregunta Daniel.
>
> — Lo han arrestado. Dicen que ha robado en un supermercado con
> Federico y otro. Ahora mismo voy... Quería saber... ¿Me puedes
> acompañar, Daniel?
>
> —Sí claro, voy contigo —dice él.
>
> Llama a Julia y le cuenta lo que ha pasado. (narrator speaking)
>
> — De acuerdo, no te preocupes por mí —dice Julia—. **Apenas
> acabas, ven.** (julia still speaking)

¿Puede significar "As soon as you are done, come see me" o algo así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed means `As soon as you are done, come see me`.

[Apenas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=38BNs6H) can have the meaning of `as soon as`

> 4. adv. **en cuanto** (‖ inmediatamente después). Apenas bajé a la calle, se puso a llover.

I have to say that I would have favored *subjuntive* for the verb tense

> Apenas *acabes*, ven

But the use of the present tense gives some sense of urgency to the statement.

So depending on the country, you couls also hear

> En cuanto *termines*, ven
>
> En cuanto *hayas acabado*, ven